# HTTP Link to JIRA advanced query

Tags: jira

I have an advanced query in JIRA that I run a lot

```
assignee = currentUser() and resolution = 'Unresolved' ORDER BY priority DESC
```

I guess it is pretty self explanatory, I only get what I have to do by order of priorities.

How can I bookmark this query? I want to link directly to a page where that query is ran and not type it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also look up in the top right corner next to views where there is a symbol like a chain link. That is a URL that you can book mark for a query

Answer (score 1):

You should save the query first, then if you mouse over the link to the saved query you will get a url.  Something like:

```
http://jira.mycompany.org/issues/?filter=11328
```